Python yfinance library
I have an Excel file with company names in column A. I want to use Python's yfinance library to populate the stock tickers into column B where they match column A. For testing purposes, I've limited my table to just one company name, Adobe, Inc.
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
!pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf
import time
 
# Import Existing Excel
excel_file_path = 'MyFilePath/Company Ticker Report.xlsx'
 
# Load Excel data
excel_df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name= 'MS LIst')
 
 
def get_ticker(company_name):
    for CompanyNamein excel_df:
        try:
            ticker_dictionary = yf.Ticker(company_name)
            print(type(ticker_dictionary)) # confirm type
            print(ticker_dictionary)  # test print dict
            related_tickers = [] 
            for row in ticker_dictionary['rows']: 
                for news in row['news']: 
                    if 'relatedTickers' in news: 
                        related_tickers.append(news['relatedTickers']) # This should return the ticker for CompanyName
            time.sleep(1) # Pause execution of function for one second
            return related_tickers
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")  # All errors
            return 'No Info'
# Apply the function to the CompanyName column
excel_df['Suggested Ticker'] = excel_df['CompanyName'].apply(get_ticker)
# Save the updated data back to Excel
excel_df.to_excel('Company Ticker Report.xlsx', index=False)
display(excel_df) # test print

When run my code, it tells me that the type for yf.Ticker is ticker, which is I think is the source of my problem (Here's the output: <class 'yfinance.ticker.Ticker'>). I then get this error message: An unexpected error occurred: 'Ticker' object is not subscriptable. I was able to convert ticker_dictionary to a dictionary with .dict, but then I could no longer refernce the nested containers inside of it that contained the data I needed (rows[news[relatedTickers]]]).
Any suggestions on how to resolve this?
When run my code, it tells me that the type for yf.Ticker is ticker, which is I think is the source of my problem (Here's the output: <class 'yfinance.ticker.Ticker'>). I then get this error message: An unexpected error occurred: 'Ticker' object is not subscriptable. I was able to convert ticker_dictionary to a dictionary with .dict, but then I could no longer refernce the nested containers inside of it that contained the data I needed (rows[news[relatedTickers]]]).
Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Try changing two lines for row in ticker_dictionary['rows']: and for news in row['news']: to one for news in ticker_dictionary.news:. Aside, it seems that a space is missing in:for CompanyNamein excel_df:.

Same error unfortunately

Here is the simplified code (I just tried to address the Ticker object error):
import yfinance as yf
import time

def get_ticker(company_name):
        try:
            dat = yf.Ticker(company_name)
            related_tickers = []
            for news in dat.news:
                if 'relatedTickers' in news:
                    related_tickers.append(news['relatedTickers'])
            time.sleep(1) # Pause execution of function for one second
            return related_tickers
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")  # All errors
            return 'No Info'

print(get_ticker('AAPL'))

Here is the output I got:
[['NVDA', 'AAPL', 'TSLA', 'META', 'MSFT'], ['AAPL'], ['BABWF', 'AAPL'], ['AAPL'], ['AVGO', 'NVDA', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'AAPL'], ['NVDA', 'AAPL', 'META', '^GSPC'], ['AAPL'], ['AAPL', 'QCOM']]


Okay that worked for outputting back to my table, thanks for your help! The next step for me is figuring out how to just pull in the text of a single ticker (ex(AAPL for Apple, with no other additional text).
